# How do I correct this error - I am following a tutorial and got stuck

Tags: python

```
final_prices = []
prices = soup.find_all("p", class_="price")
for price in prices:
    original_price = price.find("span", class_="rrp")
    if original_price:
        current_price = str(original_price.previousSibling).strip()
        current_price = float(current_price.split("€")[0].replace(",", "."))
    else:
        current_price = float(price.get_text(strip=True).split("€")[0].replace(",", "."))
        final_prices.append(current_price)
```

Output:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-d830036989c5> in <module>
      5     if original_price:
      6         current_price = str(original_price.previousSibling).strip()
----> 7         current_price = float(current_price.split("€")[0].replace(",", "."))
      8     else:
      9         current_price = float(price.get_text(strip=True).split("€")[0].replace(",", "."))

ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Comment: See how to create a [mcve] and edit the question.

Comment: You can convert the empty string to a `float`: i.e. `float('')` — which apparently is what's happening. You can check for that beforehand, or wrap the line in a `try`/`except ValueError:` and handle the problem gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it is trying to convert a blank string (`''`) to a float. That won't do. You need to figure out which price in your list of prices is `''`, or that evaluates to that by that time in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct, and it is telling you exactly what's wrong. It is saying that you have a situation where the first piece of "current_price", after it is split on `€`, is a null string. You then call `float()` on this null string, which is invalid because an empty string can't convert into a float.

This is likely because the string starts with "€", in which case if you split the string into two pieces everywhere you find a "€", then the first half will be empty (because there is nothing before the "€".

You might want to use `current_price.strip("€")` instead, especially if you expect *all* prices to begin with €. This function call will not split your string into pieces, but rather just remove all instances of € from the beginning and end of the string. This may or may not be what you want. Alternatively, you can use [1] instead of [0] in your problem to get the second piece of the split array, which likely has the number you're looking for.